# Using require in AWS lambda functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, backend

I am currently researching AWS lambda functions and I can't find anywhere if I can use the require statement in them so that I can use other, non-lambda functions. I know about zipping the node modules folder but this doesn't help me here as I don't intend to use a node module, thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can. You just have to ensure that the `node_modules` folder is uploaded as part of your package (you won't be able to use the console editor). You can read more details on the AWS Blog:

[Using Packages and Native nodejs Modules in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/)

Comment: Does this mean that the files need to go into node modules, say I have my lambda function (fn1) and another standard js function (fn2), does this mean fn2 needs to sit inside node modules?

Comment: @RohanHadnum - No. You can `require` your own files using relative paths as you would any other time (as long as you upload the files as part of your deployment package).

Answer (score 13):

Just to add to Justin's answer, yes you can require other files in lambda with this structure as an example:

```
| main.js << The handler is here
| func1.js
| func2.js
```

and in the main file:

```
// main.js
require('./func1.js');
require('./func2.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Naguib Ihab's answer. If you want to call function declared in the other JS files, you can declare that function in this way:

```
exports.handler = async () => {
  return "Hello world"
};
```

and in your invoking function:

```
const funA = require(path-to-file)
```

invoke the function by

```
funA.hanlder()
```

instead of

```
funA()
```